# Cross browser issues when CSS is applied to IFrame

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have an iFrame on my Main.html file. I have called child.html from the iFrame.
`<iframe src="child.html" id="frame1"></iframe>` (this is in Main.html file)

I need to apply CSS of Main.html to child.html file. For this I'm using an inline javascript which is in main.html.

Code is:

```
function ChangeMe() {
        var cssLink = document.createElement("link")
        cssLink.href = "Main.css";
        cssLink.rel = "stylesheet";
        cssLink.type = "text/css";
        frames['frame1'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
    }
```

This works fine only in IE 8. I want this to be running on all the browsers (FF 4,chrome).

Any suggestions!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, try something along these lines:

If you're using `<link>`:

```
$('body').append('<link rel=StyleSheet href="'+$("link:contains('Main.css')").attr('href')+'" type="text/css" media=screen />');
```

If you're using `<style>`

```
$('body').append('<style src="'+$("style:contains('Main.css')").attr('href')+'" type="text/css" media="screen" />');
```

Im not 100% sure if the syntax is spot on as I've not had a chance to test it. But its a start. Basically you want to append a `<link>` or `<style>` tag to your iframe which contains the `href=""` or `src=""` of your Main.css respectively.

**Edit**

Had a chance to code this up, you want the following:

```
$("#myFrame").contents().find("body").append('<style src="'+$("style[src='some.css']").attr('src')+'"></style>
```

Check the working example here - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/erEUW/

Answer (score -1):

Why not just link it to the child html in the first place? It needs to be declared in it's head, so since the child HTML should have a proper DOM anyway, you should include it in that page too. It really won't take that much more of your web server, as the browser will recognize that it already has the file and will just just the one downloaded upon visiting the parent HTML.



**EDIT:** Alright, after some more information regarding the needs of this script, here is a code sample of a script that I wrote. This works in my test environment, and I don't see why it wouldn't in another:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function addCSS () {

        // Connect to Child's DOM
        var ifrm = document.getElementById('childFrame');
        ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;//alert(ifrm.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML);

        // Get Child's head
        var docHead = ifrm.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML;

        // Find all Parent's CSS files
        var cssFiles = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].getElementsByTagName("link");
        for (i=0; i<cssFiles.length; i++) {

            if (cssFiles[i].getAttribute("type").toLowerCase() == 'text/css') {

                ifrm.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].innerHTML = docHead+'\n<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+cssFiles[i].getAttribute("href")+'" />';

            }

        }

    }
    document.getElementById("childFrame").addEventListener("onload", addCSS());
</script>
```

**Notes:**

1) This inline script needs to be placed AFTER the iframe had been created. Alternatively, if you can, you can add an 'onload' attribute to the iframe tag itself, calling for this function, in which case this inline JS needs to be placed BEFORE the iframe. There is no in between.

2) Many of these functions will be easier/ shorter if you use jQuery. For those who're more familiar with JS, it's quite clear that I didn't even use the appendChild() function, cause in my experience, the function doesn't always work cross-browser. In this situation I suppose I can get away with it the way I did it, as I would otherwise have to create the link tag for in the child every time, while I now just fill a string.

3) Obviously this `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].getElementsByTagName("link")` is overkill. However, this will make sure that this line will only return link tags from the header, not from anywhere else...just in case the coder of the parent script is a moron x). If you feel like this moron-proofing is as overkill as it is, you can just use `document.getElementsByTagName("link")` instead.

4) This will add ALL the CSS files that are loaded in the parent to your child.

5) ...I think I'm forgetting something, but I'm not sure what....

Comment: He definitely doesn't have access to the file otherwise he won't be asking this question ... He's including this file from some other web server or the file is served to him ... or maybe he want to add this stylesheet specifically to the page when it's loaded on the IFrame! Stop answering questions with answers like this please.

Comment: @Ahmad Alfy: It's not obviously clear from his question that he is showing his page on a remote server. The way I read it is that he has a page that is specifically meant to run as a child. Now, I could easily be wrong, but don't think I'm out of line to think this is what he meant. In all honesty, I first had this posted as a comment, but I have been previously asked, in a similar situation, to post it as an answer instead of a comment. Can't please everybody I suppose x).

Comment: Pretty unfair to vote this down. @Alfy, Sandeep said it's working in IE8. Cross-site scripting doesn't work in modern browsers, so it's reasonable to assume that "child.html" refers to a file on Sandeep's site, so Battle's question/suggestion is also reasonable. Sandeep, assuming "child.html" is a file on your system, can you explain why you can't just include CSS in the normal fashion?

Comment: Hi All,
Thanks for your valuable suggestions on my query.
My requirement is: I need an iframe in parent.html file. This iframe calls another site (child.html) which would be from the same domain. Please note I dont have access to modify the html code of parent as well as child.html pages.
I just can change the inline javascript which is in parent.html. The CSS file will be on another server. This css is to be applied to the parent.html page and the same css should be inherited by the emmbedded page (child.html).

Note: Due to space restriction, I'm unable to post the complete desciption.

Comment: Cont...
In short when I change the CSS available on another server / location, it should be applied to the child.html page.

I did more research and found a solution to it.
Below is the code:

<script type="text/javascript">

function alterMe() {
var ifrm = document.getElementById('frame1');
ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;

ifrm.document.open();  
 ifrm.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="parent.css">');  
 ifrm.document.close();  
  }

</script>

Comment: The above code works for I.E, FF, Safari and Opera, but doesn't work for Chrome browser.
I have tried almost every thing I guess to make it work on Google Chrome as well, but was of no use.

I'm not good at javascript, so any help or suggestions to make it running on Chrome would really be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm really sorry, I suppose I'm not smart enough to understand your situation. Are you saying that the location/ filename of the CSS file is subject to change? And will the parent page only contain ONE CSS file, or will there be multiple? I suppose I can figure these things out for you, but I'd like to know before I start coding.